# Giving a Single Button 3 Text Values. With User friendly interface

Tags: javascript, html

I am Making An Button With 3 Values.
-When User points on button
-When User Mouseout on button
-When User Click the Button
All These in a Single Button.
My Code is

```
<html........and declared java script code in another file.</html>
<button id="cal" onclick="calcIt()" onmouseover="showIt()" onmouseout="backOn">Calculate Values</button>
```

@JavaScript

```
//when user clicks on button
function calcIt(){

document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = "Calculation values";

}
//when user mouseovers
function showIt(){
document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = "Click To Show Value";
}
//when user mouseouts
function backOn(){
document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = "Calculate Values";
}
//i want this function to be deleted when onclick/showIt is called once
```

My Problem is I can't find a Way When User Once execute the onclick or showIt function the function backOn gets Deleted. 
Because it Won't look good when user once calculated value and System still asks to calculate

tell me if you need my code files.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//when user clicks on button
function calcIt(){

document.getElementById("cal").innerHTML = "Calculation values";

}
//when user mouseovers
function showIt(){
document.getElementById("cal").innerHTML = "Click To Show Value";
}
//when user mouseouts
function backOn(){
document.getElementById("cal").innerHTML = "Calculate Values";
}
//i want this function to be deleted when onclick/showIt is called once
```

```html
<button id="cal" onclick="calcIt()" onmouseover="showIt()" onmouseout="backOn()">Calculate Values</button>
```

Comment: you missed a function bracket in mouseout value